# Facing problem while importing MapActivity

Tags: android, import, mapactivity

Iam new to android. I got a example for accessing  google maps from some link. I got MapActivity to import in to project. Where i got error. am not able to import that tried all ways.Can any one suggest me the problem.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking project target and whether google api is avaliable in your SDK and your project.